# Extract Year from date field using jpql and jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to extract the year part from a row in the database in order to compare it with a value.

Here's my function

```
public List<Dossier> getAllDossierParAn() {
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int strI = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    TypedQuery<Dossier> query;
    query = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DOSSIER d WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR ,d.dateCreation)=2015", Dossier.class);
    System.out.println(strI);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I get always

> An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
>   Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT d FROM DOSSIER d WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d.dateCreation)=2015]. [14, 21] The abstract schema type 'DOSSIER' is unknown. [48, 62] The state field path 'd.dateCreation' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

I test it directly in the database and it works

```
select * from dossier where extract(year from date_creation)=2015
```

I'm using `jpa` and `ejb` and `jdeveloper` as IDE.

Answer (score 6):

First, the main problem with your query is what the error message say:

> The abstract schema type 'DOSSIER' is unknown

Since JPA is mapping your POJOs as entities, their names are case sensitive. Your query should be:
`SELECT d FROM Dossier d WHERE ...`

Also, regarding the problem you mentioned, the `EXTRACT` function is only supported by EclipseLink, as far as I know. By the error message, I think this is your JPA implementation, but if it's not, there are two options:

1. If you're using Hibernate, it has built in functions for retrieving date parts, such as `YEAR(date)`, `MONTH(date)`, `DAY(date)`, `HOUR(date)`, `MINUTE(date)` and `SECOND(date)`.
2. For any other JPA implementation, or if you want to keep it JPQL compliant, you can workaround with `SUBSTRING`: `SUBSTRING(d.dateCreation, 1, 4)`. Note [the first position of a string is denoted by 1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1450208589_3c085ebdc9cdca7908cd6c562adfc19b);

Hope it helps

Comment: There is nothing "JPQL compliant" about passing a DATE into SUBSTRING. SUBSTRING is for string or arithmetic expressions only.

Comment: It is, if you want it to be compatible with any implementation.

Comment: Errm, you seem not to have READ my comment. SUBSTRING can only take in string or arithmetic expressions in standardised JPQL. A DATE is neither.

Comment: Maybe you haven't read mine. This is a workaround, I understand they aren't the same type, but substring is a function shared by all implementations that will do the trick.

Comment: Oh i read yours and your answer, and the answer explicitly says "if you want to keep it JPQL compliant", and as I said that is not jpql compliant (since SUBSTRING while supported as a FUNCTION, is NOT necessarily supported to take in a DATE)... so not a "workaround".

Answer (score 1):

"Directly in the database" is called SQL.

`createQuery` takes in JPQL not SQL, and YEAR / EXTRACT are invalid keywords (though YEAR, but not EXTRACT, is supported by some JPA providers). Any decent JPA docs would spell that out.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys i solved the problem:
first i got the current year than format it to int than to String in order to do the comparaison and substract it here's my code it work fine:

```
    public List<Dossier> getAllDossierParAn() {
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int strI = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   String strInt  =Integer.toString(strI);
    String nvlstri= strInt.substring(2, 4);
    TypedQuery<Dossier> query;
    query = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Dossier d WHERE SUBSTRING(d.dateCreation, 7, 2) = :vr", Dossier.class);
  query.setParameter("vr",nvlstri);
   System.out.println("l anne est " +strI);
   System.out.println("la date formaté " +nvlstri);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Didi you try the YEAR() method?

Answer (score 0):

On eclipselink, the way that works for me was something like:

```
SELECT  a.id, EXTRACT(WEEK CURRENT_DATE ) FROM Account a
```

This works on postgres and sql server at least but should work with other supported databases too.

From [javadocs](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExtractExpression.html) the syntax supported is :

```
extract_expression ::= EXTRACT(date_part_literal [FROM] scalar_expression)
```

The FROM seems to cause funny exceptions on sql server.