# How to extract year from date in jpql?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How to extract full year from date field in jpql ?

ex: 06-SEP-17  ->From this i wanted to get year as 2017

```
@Query(value = "SELECT stud FROM Student stud where stud.doj = '2017' ") //in this query doj is in 06-SEP-17 format, my requirement is to extract full year from this and compare.
List<Student> getStudents()
```

Comment: If `stud.doj` is a genuine date, you can select between the begining and the end of year : `where doj >= 1/1/2017 and doj < 1/1/2018`.

Comment: is there any way to extract year in jpql ?

Comment: you can find solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295105/extract-year-from-date-field-using-jpql-and-jpa